# Why three (redundant?) accelerometer variations in android sensors

Tags: android, android-sensors

In android, we have Sensor.TYPE_GRAVITY, Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER, Sensor.TYPE_LINEAR_ACCELERATION.

And it is known from android developer forum that,
"The output of the accelerometer, gravity and linear-acceleration sensors must obey the following relation:
acceleration = gravity + linear-acceleration"

Do Sensor.TYPE_GRAVITY and Sensor.TYPE_LINEAR_ACCELERATION make use of the same sensor as Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER - i.e., the accelerometer?
What is purpose of having 3 different constants if the value of one can be deduced using the other using low pass and high pass filters?

Answer (score 1):

It's because  TYPE_LINEAR_ACCELERATION and TYPE_GRAVITY are available since API Level 9 (Android 2.3). If you want to build an application in a lower API version, you will only have access to TYPE_ACCELEROMETER (since API Level 3).
TYPE_LINEAR_ACCELERATION and TYPE_GRAVITY are really helpful and makes unnecessary to split TYPE_ACCELEROMETER. I deploy for Android 2.2 (API Level 8) and still don't know how to do it!

More info: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Sensor.html

Answer (score 0):

If you want more detailed information about those new "fused" sensors, have a look at the answers to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7858759/android-type-linear-acceleration-sensor-what-does-it-show).
There you will find the explanation of the different types of sensors, [directly](http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/msg/be010c01b90daa79) from one of the Google developers working on these topics.