# Android Linear Acceleration

Tags: android, input, accelerometer

Can the accelerometer detect the **movement of the device** (e.g. if I drag the device up, down, left, or right)? Please provide a sample implementation.

Answer (score 4):

Accelerometers and gyroscopes can detect device's angle and acceleration on the 3 axes.

Since the acceleration itself does not tell you the speed nor distance, you can know them.

**BUT** if you know the device's speed is currently 0, and it begins to accelerate, you can know its speed and distance by basic physics equations:
You track the device acceleration. lets make the tracking resolution to be milliseconds. So each millisecond, `speed += Acceleration * 0.001` and `distance += (speed * 0.001) + (Acceleration * 0.001 * 0.001 /2)`. This tracks movement in a **single direction.**

Notice that you have to decide what is the direction of the acceleration, speed and distance, which will be a Vector3. Then use some maths transformations to transform the current acceleration vector to your direction. I suggest that the direction will be flat comparing to the earth. Makes stuff easier later.

This can be used to tell if the device is moving (`speed!=0`, although if the movement is **exactly** perpendicular to your vector, the device might be moving but `speed==0` is true) and which direction is the movement

Answer (score 2):

Accelerometers detect acceleration, not constant motion. So your accelerometer will detect motion as it starts and stops, but can't tell you how far your device moved.

Answer (score 0):

please, look at this thread: [Android TYPE_LINEAR_ACCELERATION sensor - what does it show?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7858759/android-type-linear-acceleration-sensor-what-does-it-show)

I detect speed, movement of device using accelerometer. But i have trouble when using LINEAR_ACCELEROMETER sensor.
Anyway, it's impossible to calculate movement without calibration at start point.

Comment: So you detect movement with accelerometer? Can you give me am idea how to implement this? I'm very thank to you if you would

Answer (score 0):

There's a good example of how to calculate linear acceleration from a regular Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER on the Android Developer site:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/SensorEvent.html#values