# ANDROID: How to retrieve values from Sensor.TYPE_LINEAR_ACCELERATION?

Tags: android, accelerometer, android-sensors

When using the classic TYPE_ACCELEROMETER sensor, you can do something like:

```
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent sensorEvent){
   if (sensorEvent.sensor.getType()==Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER){
      ax=sensorEvent.values[0];
   }
}
```

BUT, when using TYPE_LINEAR_ACCELERATION, how is it supposed to provide the info?

I've tried to do things like:

```
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent sensorEvent){
       if (sensorEvent.sensor.getType()==Sensor.TYPE_LINEAR_ACCELERATION){
          ax=sensorEvent.values[0];
       }
    }
```

But it's not working. I've seen the post
[Android TYPE_LINEAR_ACCELERATION sensor - what does it show?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7858759/android-type-linear-acceleration-sensor-what-does-it-show)
And also I've looked the official documentation:
[Sensor](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Sensor.html) and
[SensorEvent](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/SensorEvent.html)
Which are very interesting indeed, but don't talk about how they took the samples. Any Idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, it's with

```
sensorEvent.values[0] // for X-Axis
sensorEvent.values[1] // for Y-Axis
sensorEvent.values[2] // for Z-Axis
```

It was MY fault, because I didn't register the listener properly.

So, In conclussion:

`TYPE_LINEAR_ACCELERATION` is used like the tradiotional `TYPE_ACCELEROMETER`