# Acceleration and deceleration of car using Android device

Tags: android, accelerometer, sensors

I tried and found the speed of the car through `location.getSpeed();` and location using GPS in Android and now I want to find acceleration and deceleration of the car. For that do I have any Android device parameters like GPS, or do I need to calculate from speed and time what I have now? I came to know that there is acceleration in the device, it is giving coordinates. I want to know how to calculate car acceleration and deceleration. Help with some work outs or any suggestions.

Answer (score 2):

Use android sensor `TYPE_LINEAR_ACCELERATION`

Comment: There is a similar question already, please check this:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7858759/android-type-linear-acceleration-sensor-what-does-it-show