# android - detect downward acceleration, specifically an elevator

Tags: android, accelerometer, android-sensors, hardware-acceleration

I want to be able to detect a situation where the phone has an acceleration towards the ground (probably means that the Gravity sensor has to be used here also).

I have read a lot about this topic in the Android docs, about High and Low pass filters and other posts, and right now what I have is a code sample that gets the acceleration in the X, Y and Z axis after stripping the gravity:

```
if (event.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER) {

        final float alpha = (float) 0.8;

        gravity[0] = alpha * gravity[0] + (1 - alpha) * event.values[0];
        gravity[1] = alpha * gravity[1] + (1 - alpha) * event.values[1];
        gravity[2] = alpha * gravity[2] + (1 - alpha) * event.values[2];

        linear_acceleration[0] = event.values[0] - gravity[0];
        linear_acceleration[1] = event.values[1] - gravity[1];
        linear_acceleration[2] = event.values[2] - gravity[2];  
}
```

So, the `linear_acceleration` is supposedly the acceleration in the X, Y, Z axis without the gravity.

This is all nice, but the problem obviously is that is depends on how the user holds the phone, for example, in the elevator - if he holds it flat, parallel to the ground - the `Z axis` will change, if he holds it up straight - the `Y axis` will change , etc.

So, for example, if the user holds the phone diagonally, the acceleration will be "divided" between the different axes, and some sort of math work, considering where the gravity direction is, will be needed to calculate the actual acceleration in that direction.

Correct me if I am wrong?

Is there a reliable way to detect the downward (towards the earth) acceleration? maybe using other sensors like Gyroscope?

BTW - about the `TYPE_LINEAR_ACCELERATION` type, I read this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7858759/android-type-linear-acceleration-sensor-what-does-it-show), saying that its actually not very accurate.

Comment: Can you use the axis value that is changing the most?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use some basic physics.  Acceleration is a vector.  The magnitude of a vector v is always equal to (v.v)^.5, or the square root of the dot product.  Or in simpler terms (x^2+y^2+z^2)^.5.  That will tell you the amount of acceleration, but not if its towards or away from the earth.

If you need to know if its going towards or away from earth-  you can combine that with data from SensorManager.getOrientation.  You may need to do that before they enter the elevator though-  the orientation code uses gravity as one of its inputs, so it may be screwed up if you try to use it in an elevator.  You'd need to test it out.

If you need to break it down to acceleration in terms of earth x, y, and z axes-  simple geometry.  Take the angle from the orientation result, and use trig properties to convert axes.  If you don't know the formulas you need to read up on trig a bit or you'll get them wrong even if I tell them to you.

Comment: thanks for your answer. I did manage to get to overall acceleration using your formula, and I have the pitch, roll and azimuth angles of the orientation - but I am really not sure how to continue from here and get the acceleration towards the earth.

Comment: Can you share the formula?

Answer (score 1):

I also wanted to just be able to measure vertical movement. This is how I did it and it worked for me. First time posting on this site and I have no idea how to format correctly.

Use two different android Sensors: `Type_linear_Acceleration and Type_Gravity`

Linear acceleration will give you acceleration in the X, Y and Z axis of the phone, and Gravity will do the same, but just for gravity. You know that the sum of the gravity values should = 9.8, but this will be split between X, Y and Z coordinates depending on the phone orientation.

I wont go into the math of it too much, but the following will give you vertical acceleration without gravity. If you want to understand it a bit more run through some values as if the phone was held vertically, then horizontally, it works even if the phone is oblique.

> vertical acceleration = (LinearAccelX * GravityX / 9.8)+ (LinearAccelY * GravityY / 9.8)+ (LinearAccelZ * GravityZ / 9.8).

See  code below (irrelevant parts removed):

```
{public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements SensorEventListener {

SensorManager sm;
Sensor linearaccelerometer;
Sensor gravity;
double Yaccel;
double Xaccel;
double Zaccel;
double gravityY;
double gravityX;
double gravityZ;
double verticalAccel;

    sm = (SensorManager) getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE);
    linearaccelerometer = sm.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_LINEAR_ACCELERATION);
    gravity = sm.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_GRAVITY);

    sm.registerListener(this, linearaccelerometer, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
    sm.registerListener(this, gravity, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
}

public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {

    Sensor sensor = event.sensor;

    if (sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_LINEAR_ACCELERATION) {
        Xaccel = (double) event.values[0];
        Yaccel = (double) event.values[1];
        Zaccel = (double) event.values[2];
    }

    if (sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_GRAVITY) {
        gravityX = (double) event.values[0];
        gravityY = (double) event.values[1];
        gravityZ = (double) event.values[2];
    }

    verticalAccel = (Xaccel * gravityX / 9.8) + (Yaccel * gravityY / 9.8) +  (Zaccel *gravityZ /9.8);

}
```