# Android accelerometer calibration?

Tags: android, accelerometer, sensors, android-sensors, gyroscope

> **TL;DR**
>
> How come the accelerometer values I get from `Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER` are slightly offset? I don't mean by gravity, but by some small error that varies from axis to axis and phone to phone.
>
> Can I calibrate the accelerometer? Or is there a standard way of compensating for these errors?

I'm developing an app that has a need for as precise acceleration measurements as possible (mainly vertical acceleration, i.e. same direction as gravity).

I've been doing A LOT of testing, and it turns out that the raw values I get from `Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER` are off. If I let the phone rest at a perfectly horizontal surface with the screen up, the accelerometer shows a Z-value of 9.0, where it should be about 9.81. Likewise, if I put the phone in portrait or landscape mode, the X- and Y- accelerometer values show about 9.6. instead of 9.81.

This of course affects my vertical acceleration, as I'm using `SensorManager.getRotationMatrixFromVector()`, to calculate the vertical acceleration, resulting in a vertical acceleration that is off by a different amount depending on the rotation of the device.

Now, before anyone jumps the gun and mentions that I should try using `Sensor.TYPE_LINEAR_ACCELERATION` instead, I must point out that I'm actually doing that as well, parallel to the `TYPE_ACCELERATION`. By using the gravity sensor I then calculate the vertical acceleration ([as described in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39333427/930640)). The funny thing is that I get EXACTLY the same result as the method that uses the raw accelerometer, `SensorManager.getRotationMatrixFromVector()` and matrix multiplication (and finally subtracting gravity).

The only way I'm able to get almost exactly zero vertical acceleration for a stationary phone in any rotation is to get the raw accelerometer values, add an offset (from earlier observations, i.e. `X+0.21`, `Y+0.21` and `Z+0.81`) and then performing the rotation matrix stuff to get the world coordinate system accelerations. Note that since it's not just the calculated vertical acceleration that is wrong - it's actually the raw values from `Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER`, which I would think excludes other error sources like gyroscope sensor, etc?

I have tested this on two different phones (Samsung Galaxy S5 and Sony Xperia Z3 compact), and both have these accelerometer value deviances - but of course not the same values on both phones.

How come the the values of `Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER` are off, and is there a better way of "calibrating" the accelerometer than simply observing how much they deviate from gravity and adding the difference to the values before using them?

Comment: This is known as Zero Offset, Offset or Bias. If the device remains stationary the average accelerometer measurement should read (0, 0, -/+SensorManager.GRAVITY_EARTH m/s²) [depending on the handedness of the coordinate frame], if not however, the accelerometer sensor is biased. Adding/subtracting an offset to "correct" the bias is the way to go :)!

Answer (score 2):

You should calibrate gains, offsets, and angle of the 3 accelerometers.

Unfortunately it's not possible to deepen the whole topic here.
I'll write a small introduction, describing the basic concept, and then I'll post a link to the code of a simple Clinometer that implements the calibration.

The calibration routine could be done with 7 misurations (calculate the mean value of a good number of samples) in different ortogonal positions at your choice, in order to have all +-0 and +-g values of your accelerometers. For example:

- STEP 1 = Lay flat
- STEP 2 = Rotate 180°
- STEP 3 = Lay on the left side
- STEP 4 = Rotate 180°
- STEP 5 = Lay vertical
- STEP 6 = Rotate 180° upside-down
- STEP 7 = Lay face down

Then you can use the 7 measurements `mean[][]` to calculate offsets and gains:

```
calibrationOffset[0] = (mean[0][2] + mean[0][3]) / 2;
calibrationOffset[1] = (mean[1][4] + mean[1][5]) / 2;
calibrationOffset[2] = (mean[2][0] + mean[2][6]) / 2;

calibrationGain[0] = (mean[0][2] - mean[0][3]) / (STANDARD_GRAVITY * 2);
calibrationGain[1] = (mean[1][4] - mean[1][5]) / (STANDARD_GRAVITY * 2);
calibrationGain[2] = (mean[2][0] - mean[2][6]) / (STANDARD_GRAVITY * 2);
```

using the values of `mean[axis][step]`, where `STANDARD_GRAVITY = 9.81`.
Then apply the Gain and Offset Corrections to measurements:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
    mean[0][i] = (mean[0][i] - calibrationOffset[0]) / calibrationGain[0];
    mean[1][i] = (mean[1][i] - calibrationOffset[1]) / calibrationGain[1];
    mean[2][i] = (mean[2][i] - calibrationOffset[2]) / calibrationGain[2];
}
```

and finally calculates the correction angles:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
    angle[0][i] = (float) (Math.toDegrees(Math.asin(mean[0][i]
        / Math.sqrt(mean[0][i] * mean[0][i] + mean[1][i] * mean[1][i] + mean[2][i] * mean[2][i]))));
    angle[1][i] = (float) (Math.toDegrees(Math.asin(mean[1][i]
        / Math.sqrt(mean[0][i] * mean[0][i] + mean[1][i] * mean[1][i] + mean[2][i] * mean[2][i]))));
    angle[2][i] = (float) (Math.toDegrees(Math.asin(mean[2][i]
        / Math.sqrt(mean[0][i] * mean[0][i] + mean[1][i] * mean[1][i] + mean[2][i] * mean[2][i]))));
}

calibrationAngle[2] =  (angle[0][0] + angle[0][1])/2;       // angle 0 = X axis
calibrationAngle[1] = -(angle[1][0] + angle[1][1])/2;       // angle 1 = Y axis
calibrationAngle[0] = -(angle[1][3] - angle[1][2])/2;       // angle 2 = Z axis
```

You can find a simple but complete implementation of a 3-axis calibration in this opensource Clinometer app: https://github.com/BasicAirData/Clinometer.
There is also the APK and the link of the Google Play Store if you want to try it.

- You can find the calibration routine in `CalibrationActivity.java`;
- The calibration parameters are applied in `ClinometerActivity.java`.

Furthermore, you can find a very good technical article that deepens the 3-axis calibration here: https://www.digikey.it/it/articles/using-an-accelerometer-for-inclination-sensing.